# Difference between 'save' and 'update' in using with different http requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I tried replacing `@post.update` with `@post.save` as in my code below, it still worked and it returned true, but the values were not updated.

```
 def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

below are my rake routes:

```
$ rake routes
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
     root        /                         welcome#index
```

Why didn't it update or overwrite my record?

Will using different http requests for the same methods have any effect on them? Can we use `PUT`, `GET`, `PATCH` and `DELETE` for save when passed with proper syntax?

The question is regarding rails 4 guide, the first [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Comment: "when i tried replacing @post.update with @post.save", you mean you code like this `@post.save(post_params)` in update action?

Comment: write update_attributes instead of update.

Comment: yes, i overlooked that part newbie as i am.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because `save` will not accept the attributes as parameters; `save` can only accept parameters like `validate: false` to skip validation.

If you want to use `save`, then you need to assign or modify individual attributes before `save`. But if you want mass-assignment, `update` would be your choice.

```
@post.f_name = 'foo'
@post.l_name = 'bar'    
@post.update # This will not work
@post.save # This will work

@post.save({:f_name=>"peter",:l_name=>"parker"}) # This will not work
@post.update({:f_name=>"peter",:l_name=>"parker"}) # This will work
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I overlooked that part. My general question was whether using different http requests for same methods will have any effect on them ?
or for example: can we use PUT, GET, PATCH and DELETE for save, when passed with proper syntax?

Comment: Nope...`save` and `updates` have no idea about the request headers, No matter what kind of request you give their process will be same

Answer (score 10):

[1] http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html provides a good explanation.

> **save(*) Link**

Saves the model.

**If the model is new a record gets created in the database, otherwise the existing record gets updated.**

By default, save always run validations. If any of them fail the action is cancelled and save returns false. However, if you supply validate: false, validations are bypassed altogether.

> **save!(*) Link**

Saves the model.

If the model is new a record gets created in the database, otherwise the existing record gets updated.

With save! validations always run. If any of them fail ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid gets raised.

> **update(attributes) Link**

**Updates the attributes of the model from the passed-in hash and saves the record, all wrapped in a transaction.** If the object is invalid, the saving will fail and false will be returned.
Also aliased as: update_attributes

> **update!(attributes) Link**

Updates its receiver just like update but calls save! instead of save, so an exception is raised if the record is invalid.
Also aliased as: update_attributes!

Answer (score -2):

To be precise : 1. Save will save your all instances of class which may not require to that. Especially when validation is present.
e.g @post.save
It will update all the attributes or column for post.

1. Update will just update a single attribute of the class or the respective model of that particular class
   @post.update(:status,present).